# Application specific DNS problem?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ffmpeg

I'm working on a live stream transcoder application using nginx + ffmpeg.

Everything works fine when I use avconv to transcode, but if I use ffmpeg, I get this error:

```
[tcp @ 0xb4e9da0] Failed to resolve hostname fso.dca.XXXX.edgecastcdn.net: System error
```

Any hints? Seems like an application specific firewall.

Comment: What versions of `ffmpeg` are you using + `avconv`?

Comment: avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: ffmpeg version 2.4.3-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: That msg is being thrown from `ffmpeg`, here's the source: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.0/tcp_8c-source.html.Is there an issue with the hostname resolution?

Comment: Someone else experiencing your same issue: http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Failed-to-resolve-hostname-Ubuntu-static-builds-td4667782.html. Based on this it seems to be an issue with the static build, at least on the surface. I'd confirm what options  the static was built with, it might be missing options that make this feature work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the static build, as @slm mentioned. I've compiled ffmpeg from source and things work fine now.